# Application memory management problems

Tags: java, android, memory-management, heap-memory

I use this bunch of code to check my phone's memory details in application's onCreate() method:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
int memoryClass = am.getMemoryClass();
long maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
long totalMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
Log.i("ilog", "memoryClass: " + memoryClass);
Log.i("ilog", "maxMemory: " + maxMemory);
Log.i("ilog", "totalMemory: " + totalMemory);
```

memoryClass and maxMemory seems okay and are always the same as it should be lol, but everytime I open my app totalMemory is increasing. For example: on my Samsung Galaxy S3 it starts from around 12005651 bytes and goes up to 14000000 bytes after 10 openings of my app. Is this normal? Because I think that after I close my app memory should be freed and when I open it again it should be as it was when I opened it first time: around 12 MB. However, if I kill my app by clearing "Recent apps" list it goes back to 12MB.

Comment: Use [MAT](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMemoryAnalyzer/article.html) for Android to check which process is consuming your memory.